Limit for Brownian local time
If we denote $(B(t))_{t\geq 0}$ as the standard Brownian motion, as by the scaling property, we know for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we have $\frac{B(nt)}{\sqrt{n}}\overset{(d)}{=}B(t)$, and denote for every $n$, $L^{(n)}(t)$ is the Brownian local time for the standard brownian motion $\frac{B(nt)}{\sqrt{n}}$. As we know for any fixed $t\geq 0$, we have $L^{(n)}(t)<\infty$ a.s., my question is: for fixed $t$, do we have $\frac{\log L^{(n)}(t)}{\log n}\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ (almost surely or in probability or in law)? I think my question is due to there's an index $n$ in $L^{(n)}(t)$ the Brownian local time.

I think I have an answer: can you please let me know if you spot any mistake? Here we can write for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$,
$L^{(n)}(t)=\frac{L(nt)}{\sqrt{n}}$ and $L^{(n)}(t)\overset{(d)}{=}L{(t)}$, thus $\frac{\log L^{(n)}(t)}{\log n}\overset{(d)}{=}\frac{\log L(t)}{\log n}$ and since $\frac{\log L(t)}{\log n}\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ a.s. we have $\frac{\log L^{(n)}(t)}{\log n}\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ in probability.
